# Where is output file created after running FileWriter in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, filewriter

This is how I am writing to file. (Scala code)

```
import java.io.FileWriter
val fw = new FileWriter("my_output_filename.txt", true)
fw.write("something to write into output file")
fw.close()
```

This is part of a spark job I'm running on AWS EMR. Thw job runs and finishes successfully. The problem is I'm unable to locate `my_output_filename.txt` anywhere once it's done.

A bit more context:
What I'm trying to do: Doing some processing on each row of a dataframe and writing it into a file. so it looks something like this:

```
myDF.collect().foreach( row => {
import java.io.FileWriter
val fw = new FileWriter("my_output_filename.txt", true)
fw.write("row data to be written into file")
fw.close()
})
```

How I checked:
When I ran it in local, I found newly created file in same directory where code is present. But couldn't find it in remote node.
I ran `find / -name "my_output_filename.txt"`.
I also checked in HDFS: `hdfs dfs -find / -name "my_output_filename.txt"`

1. Where can I find the output file ?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why don't you use the `.write` method of a dataframe?

Comment: yeah, I might end up doing that. But my question still remains.